# Querying MediaStore.Images.Media , how do I query both on EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI?

Tags: android, android-image, mediastore

And first of all thanks for your help.

I think this should be a rather trivial question for somebody not new to querying Content Providers.

I need to query **MediaStore.Images.Media** to obtain ALL the images on the device, both on internal storage and on an sd card.

This is the query I have in mind:

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

actualimagecursor = 
managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,null, null, null);
```

the point is that I want to query **both** EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.

Is it possible to perform it with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve both results with a single query since the query is permofmed in a specific location (internal or external). You need yo instantiate two dirrefent `Cursors`.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I suspected. Please can you suggest how can I create a single cursor merging two cursors, e.g. copying both cursor in a single "cursor-like" object. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this is too old to help, but you can use MergeCursor to combine the two queries.

```
Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[2];
cursors[0] = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE ,
    },
    null,
    null,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
);
cursors[1] = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
       new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE
       },
       null,
       null,
       MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
);
Cursor cursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);
```